# PHP regex match all urls

Tags: php, regex

I need help creating a Regex that will match all urls for example, please do not close question as a duplicate as I have been looking for what i need for a long time, and none of the answers i have seen have given an answer that solves my problem.

website.com

www.website.com

http://www.website.com

http://website.com

https://www.website.com

https://website.com

with also anything trailing

www.website.com/path-to-something

I am coding something that shortens any url, but to do so, first i need to match them all.

Thanks

Comment: What's your effort so far ?

Comment: I've tried a whole load of different expressions, Regex isns't exactly my forte... (http://[^ ]+) that is all i have right now, but it only matches one kind.

Comment: @Spudley: Don't think so since `website.com` is not a valid URL and the usecase is different. OP wants to search for matching base URLs.

Comment: @Aquillo - some of the answers on that other question would work fine. But really, the only difference between a valid URL and `website.com` is making the protocol part optional in the regex.

Comment: Use following RegEx, it's more generic:

preg_match_all(@((((ht)|(f))tp[s]?://)|(www\.))([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)?([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+[/]?[a-z0-9._\/~#&=;%+?-]*@si', $input, $result);

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This one match correctly all you posted:

```
preg_match_all('#[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si', $targetString, $result);
```

Comment: Please ellaborate...?

Comment: I get an error with that: Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '{' i do i need to wrap it in something?

Comment: This works in JS, I'll try to convert it.

Comment: yes, you need to wrap it into some symbol that not used in the expression, i.e. $expression$

Comment: I converted it for you.

Comment: @LakatosGyula, your edited expression will not work because character `#` already exists in expression

Comment: I fixed that 2 mins ago. :) Escaped them with '\' so now it works correctly.

Comment: @AndréFigueira This is wrong in so many ways. It's a real bad way to go about doing this and the regex will match invalid strings like for instance something like this `=.website.com` or `@@@@@.website.com` and many other invalid URLs. You should not be using a regex for this.

Comment: @AndréFigueira see my answer below that solves this.

Comment: this one is better for any valid url like anything.com/fewfrwg/wgrwgr ^(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*(\/[^\/]+)*(\/)?$

Comment: WARNING: This doesn't work! It matches the string `name...like` as a URL

Comment: This does not grab query parameters either.

Comment: Doesn't work at all.        $x = "https://www.google.com";
        $x = preg_replace('#[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si', "$1", $x);

Answer (score 5):

You want to use something like this:

```
$string = 'www.blah.com';

$temp_string = (!preg_match('#^(ht|f)tps?://#', $string)) // check if protocol not present
    ? 'http://' . $string // temporarily add one
    : $string; // use current

if (filter_var($temp_string, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
    echo 'is valid';
} else {
    echo 'not valid';
}
```

This uses PHP's build in URL validation. It will first check to see if a protocol is present, if it is not it will temporarily add one to a string to be checked then run it through validation. This is accurate unlike the currently accepted answer.

Comment: Does this match things like gooogle.com and www.google.com?

Comment: yes http://viper-7.com/Jz7nR1 and yes http://viper-7.com/Iv9SiS

Comment: What the above code does is if it finds a URL that is invalid in the sense it does not begin with either http:// https:// ftp:// or ftps:// it will temporarily add http:// to make it a full URL which can then be safely passed to the PHP built in URL validation function. Otherwise if it already contains it it will just pass to the validation function as-is.

Comment: "http://googlecom" is valid according to FILTER_VALIDATE_URL. Not sure what your use is, but this isn't what I'd accept as a valid URL

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following trick :

```
$url = "your URL"
$validation = "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i";
if((bool)preg_match($validation, $url) === false)
echo 'Not a valid URL';
```

I think it may works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a regex. There's a PHP function for doing what you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: The questions is asking how to break down URL like things so that equivalent links can be checked for going to equivalent places, not whether it's valid or not. He wants to check whether the host is the same, the path is the same etc.

Comment: actually, we do shorten invalid urls, we match things that may be urls like if someone was to use google.com. technically that would be invalid, but we just look for that fix it, then shorten it.... Parse url isn't what we need, we already have a solution using regex working exactly like we want it, thanks for posting your answer anyway.

Comment: @Danack parse_url() : _This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts._